# Pyspark Systemml writing/reading from /tmp

Tags: caching, pyspark, tmp, systemml

I am running a Flask App with a systemml SVM component through pyspark.  The app runs for about a day or so, then it begins to error out whenever the SVM is used to make a prediction.  The error that is thrown is:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/systemml/_p1_10.101.38.73/cache/cache000005058.dat (No such file or directory)
```

I believe what is happening is that systemml is writing to /tmp/ which is then eventually cleared out by the container that I am using.  Then when it goes to predict it attempts to read this file and errors out.  Am I correct in that guess?  What's the best way to solve this?  Is there a way to tell systemml where to write its cache to?

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Welcome to SO. In order for others to be able to help you, please see 'How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example' https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in SystemML master (and upcoming releases) you can simply use `ml.setConfigProperty("localtmpdir", "/tmp2/systemml")` to modify this cache directory or any other configuration. However, the Python MLContext API in SystemML 0.14 didn't expose this yet.

As a workaround, you can alternatively put a `SystemML-config.xml` (see systemml/conf for templates) with your custom configurations into the directory where the SystemML.jar has been installed.